# UWP Designer View Shows, But Device Outline Missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I'm using Visual Studio to create a WPF application. I open up MainPage.xaml, and I get the designer view. However, the outline of the screen of the device I have selected is not visible, and I cannot find an area to drop my controls onto. I've attached a picture so you can see clearly.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHIwx.jpg

Thanks!

Comment: Is it not zoomed out really far, try changing the device type see if that re-triggers the designer?

Comment: @RoguePlanetoid tried that too, and different zoom levels, and still nothing shows up.

Comment: Thought was worth a try, sometimes could re-trigger layout to show up, sorry it didn't help

Comment: @NateDev Something worth a try: 1. Press Ctrl+0 to see if you can see any changes 2. Open a new blank app to see whether you have the same hehavior. Not so sure whether it is a designer issue. If it is a designer issue, you'd better report it via Visual Studio->Help->Send Feedback.

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT Works in a new project on and off, sometimes the new project will work, then a few days later it stops working as well. I've repaired my installation of VS as well. CRTL+0 did nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Try to drag and drop directly into the XAML code.

Comment: Drag and drop something from the toolbox, a button for example onto the XAML code window? Ok I will try that, thanks :)

Comment: So I dragged and dropped a button from the toolbox into the XAML code, and it added <Button /> but it still doesn't show up in the designer view.